# python "if" statement always returning false

Tags: python, if-statement

Ive looked for awnsers but they dont help.
so my code looks like this:

```
def creditsyay():
    print("Hosted by GitHub")
    print("Made by Zeplin-Reaper on GitHub. link: https://github.com/Zeplin-Reapers")
guess()
from random import random
import math
number = random() * 100
number = math.ceil(number)
print(number)
def guess():
    uNumber = input("Enter a number: ")
    if uNumber == number:
        print("correct!")
    elif uNumber == "credits()":
        creditsyay()
     else:
         print("Guess Again")
         guess()
    def main():
        guess()

main()
```

Okay, say Number = 56.
user guesses 5, computer says guess again. Okay.
user then guesses 56.
computer thinks uNumber == number = false
*Let me clarify:*
computer thinks 56 is not equal to 56
**A FIVE YEAR OLD COULD FIND THAT OUT**
I need help on how to get the computer to want to do math that a **FIVE YEAR OLD** could do!!
plz help

EDIT: print(number) is for testing

Comment: `input()` returns a string. You need to convert it to an int `if int(uNumber) == number:`

Comment: Your `number` is always an `int` while `uNumber` is always a `str`. You're comparing an integer to a string which will always result in False.

Comment: `uNumber` is a string. Closing down as a rookie error.

Comment: As for your nonsensical rant, keep in mind that computers are still terrible at things like facial recognition (on average), but the average five year old is awesome at it.

Comment: thanks! just tried it and works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
uNumber = input("Enter a number: ")
```

with

```
uNumber = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

I also made a similar program here if you are interested.
https://github.com/brendancreek/Python/blob/master/Guess.py